# Multiple row's coulmns in one row's multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Table Schema
```

---

```
ID    Status     Patient
1     critical    Gabriel   
1     moderate   Frank
1     critical   Dorin 
2     low        Peter
3     critical    Noman 
3     moderate   Johnson
```

Expected OutPut

---

```
ID   Patient1   Patient2
1    Gabriel    Dorin
3    Noman      Null
```

Here I have to show only those patient whose situation is critcal.

I found the similar question [Multiple column values in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619186/multiple-column-values-in-a-single-row), but its in SQL also the columns are hard coded.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you have 3 critical patients on the same id?

Comment: @AmitSingh I think you didn't read the question, and expected result.. :)

Comment: you are right i get it now

Comment: @FlorinGhita , then coulms should be created accoprdingly, for example there are 3 critical patient it should create 3 coulmns

Comment: Added a pivot solution in the answer. There is no report that has dinamic number of columns that can be run in a single step, or without programming. So, you should decide the number of columns :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step is to select the critical patients and order them:

```
select id, patient, row_number() over (partition by id order by patient) as rnk
from your_table
where status='critical';
```

After this you can select first two critical patients in this manner:

```
select id, 
       max(case when rnk=1 then patient end)  as Patient1,
       max(case when rnk=2 then patient end)  as Patient2
from (
    select id, 
           patient, 
           row_number() over (partition by id order by patient) as rnk
    from your_table
    where status='critical'
)
group by id;
```

If you want a more flexible solution you can try a query like below, but you should choose the number of ranks in before the runtime:

```
with your_table as 
(select 1 as id,     'critical' as status,    'Gabriel' as patient from dual 
 union all
select 1,     'moderate',   'Frank' from dual  union all 
select 1,     'critical',   'Dorin' from dual  union all
select 1,     'critical',   'Vasile' from dual  union all
select 2,     'low',        'Peter' from dual  union all
select 3,     'critical',    'Noman' from dual  union all 
select 3,     'moderate',   'Johnson' from dual )

select * from (
    select id, patient, row_number() over (partition by id order by patient) as rnk
    from your_table
    where status='critical'
    )
pivot (max(patient) for rnk in (1, 2, 3))
order by 1  ;
```

(This is for three patients.)

Comment: what when number of patients are more?

Comment: You may add here `for rnk in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. I explained you in the comments of question that a variable number of columns is not posible in plain sql.

Comment: but can be number_Of_Columns = number_Critical_Patients_Rows

Comment: It can be done programaticaly in two steps. A query to generate a query and then execute the second :). But this is not sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build query and execute the result to a cursor.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
v_fact NUMBER := 1;
v_max_cnt number:=1;
V_query CLOB:='';
BEGIN
select max(RNum) into v_max_cnt from(
  select row_number() over (partition by ID order by ID) RNum from PATIENTSTATUS where status='critical'
  )x;
FOR v_counter IN 1..v_max_cnt LOOP
  V_query := V_query||v_fact||' as Patient'||v_fact||(case when v_fact=v_max_cnt then '' else ',' end);
  v_fact:=v_fact+1;
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE  ('select * from (
    select id, patient, row_number() over (partition by id order by patient) as rnk
    from PATIENTSTATUS
    where status=''critical'')
    pivot (max(patient) for rnk in ('||V_query||'))
    order by 1;');
END;
```

From a procedure, data can be inserted to a cursor by

```
OPEN CUR_Your_Cursor FOR V_query;
```