# Using Pivoting in SQL Server (Error) - Invalid column name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, pivot, mssql-jdbc

```
SELECT 
    [Reg. number], [Surname], 
    [SESREFDATETIME1], [ATTENDANCE1], 
    [SESREFDATETIME2], [ATTENDANCE2],
    [SESREFDATETIME3], [ATTENDANCE3],
    [SESREFDATETIME4], [ATTENDANCE4] 
FROM
    (SELECT
        [Reg. number], [Surname], 
        col + CAST(rn AS varchar(10)) col, 
        value
     FROM
        (SELECT
            [Reg. number], Surname,
            row_number() over(partition by [Reg. number] order by SESREFDATETIME) rn
         FROM #Temp) t
     CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT 'SESREFDATETIME', SESREFDATETIME 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT 'ATTENDANCE', ATTENDANCE) c (col, value)
    ) x
PIVOT
    (max(value)
     for col in ([SESREFDATETIME1], [ATTENDANCE1], [SESREFDATETIME2],[ATTENDANCE2], [SESREFDATETIME3], [ATTENDANCE3], [SESREFDATETIME4],[ATTENDANCE4])
    ) p;
```

In my procedure I created a `#temp` temporary table and I tried to show multiple lines in multiple columns. The reason I used pivot because  this code created dynamically and number of rows aren't known. I am running the code but it gives error. I am going to be crazy. Can't find where is the error. It shows that in cross apply there is invalid column name. I think there is another error. And it shows error in wrong side. 
For testing table format is as following

```
Create table #Temp
(
    [Reg. number] int, 
    [Surname] Varchar(50), 
    SESREFDATETIME Varchar(80), 
    ATTENDANCE Varchar(10)
)
```

Example data format is

```
2005162 Abasov  04/09/2014 09:00 - 10:00    Y
2005458 Baxşiyev    15/04/2015 01:00 - 04:00    NULL
2005458 Baxşiyev    16/09/2014 14:00 - 17:00    Y
2005538 Abbasbəyli  13/10/2014 12:00 - 15:00    Y
```

Comment: Please show all the errors you got and try to setup a demo for your query and sample data here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3 to play with

Comment: I couldn't use sqlfiddle. Schema Creation Failed: can't connect to datasource [sqlfiddle_mssql2]: Network error IOException: Connection refused  . So I changed the question. I hope it will give you some ideas. Thank  you for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'cross apply x' can't see SESREFDATETIME and ATTENDANCE, if you include those columns in your 'subselect t' the cross apply part can get the values

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    [Reg. number], [Surname], 
    [SESREFDATETIME1], [ATTENDANCE1], 
    [SESREFDATETIME2], [ATTENDANCE2],
    [SESREFDATETIME3], [ATTENDANCE3],
    [SESREFDATETIME4], [ATTENDANCE4] 
FROM
    (SELECT
        [Reg. number], [Surname], 
        col + CAST(rn AS varchar(10)) col, 
        value
     FROM
        (SELECT
            [Reg. number], Surname,
            row_number() over(partition by [Reg. number] order by SESREFDATETIME) rn,
            SESREFDATETIME,
            ATTENDANCE
         FROM #Temp) t
     CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT 'SESREFDATETIME', SESREFDATETIME 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT 'ATTENDANCE', ATTENDANCE) c (col, value)
    ) x
PIVOT
    (max(value)
     for col in ([SESREFDATETIME1], [ATTENDANCE1], [SESREFDATETIME2],[ATTENDANCE2], [SESREFDATETIME3], [ATTENDANCE3], [SESREFDATETIME4],[ATTENDANCE4])
    ) p;
```

Comment: Great. Thank you very much for both answering and explaining .