# SQL - How to "flatten" several very similar rows into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies if the title isn't clear - I just didn't know how to describe the issue and I really don't know SQL that well/at all.

I am working with a database used by our case management system. At places it has clearly been extended over time by the developers. I am working with Contact details (names, addresses, etc...) and they have added extra fields to deal with email addresses and to allow for home/work/mobile phone numbers etc...

The problem is that they haven't added a new field for each individual new field. They have instead added a couple of fields in 2 different tables - the first field includes the field name, the second then includes the actual data.

The first is called AddElTypeText in a table called AdditionalAddElTypes - The AddElTypeText field includes values like "Work Telephone 1", "Fax", "Home Email" etc... (There are a total of 10 different values and I can't see the developers expanding this number any time soon)

The second field is called AddElementText in a table called AdditionalAddressElements - the AddElementText then includes the actual data e.g. the phone number, email address.

For those of you who (unlike me) find it easier to look at the SQL code, it's:

```
SELECT
  Address.AddressLine1
  ,AdditionalAddElTypes.AddElTypeText
  ,AdditionalAddressElements.AddElementText
FROM
  Address
  INNER JOIN AdditionalAddressElements
    ON Address.AddressID = AdditionalAddressElements.AddressID
  INNER JOIN AdditionalAddElTypes
    ON AdditionalAddressElements.AddElTypeID = AdditionalAddElTypes.AddElTypeID
```

I can work with this, but if any contact has 2 or more "additional" elements, I get multiple rows, with most of the data being the same, but just the 2 columns of AddElTypeText and AddElementText being different.

So can anyone suggest anything to "flatten" a contact into a single row. I had in mind something like concatenating AddElTypeText and AddElementText into a single string field, ideally with a space in between AddElTypeText  and AddElementText, and then a : or , separating the pairs of AddElTypeText  and AddElementText.

However, I have very little idea how to achieve that, or whether an entirely different approach would be better. Any help very gratefully received!

Gary

Comment: Can you edit your post with your create table statements for each table, some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: There are other questions where strings grouping is discussed, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server). In some RDBMs there are already built-in functions for this (e.g. in PostgreSQL there is `array_agg()`.

Comment: Please post sample data, current output and desired output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619186/multiple-column-values-in-a-single-row

Comment: thanks everyone - I think the biggest part of my problem was how to describe it, so couldn't search. I'll look through all the links and provide more info if I need further help. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @twn08 said, this type of question has generally been asked before. It's generally a pain to do this kind of grouping concatenation in SQL Server, involving the use of `FOR XML`.

That being said, [here's a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4c68/2) that (I believe) does something like what you wanted. And here's the actual query:

```
WITH Results AS
(
  SELECT a.*,
    t.AddElTypeText,
    aa.AddElementText
  FROM
    Address a
  INNER JOIN
    AdditionalAddressElements aa
    ON a.AddressID = aa.AddressID
  INNER JOIN
    AdditionalAddElTypes t
    ON aa.AddElTypeID = t.AddElTypeID
)
SELECT
  res.AddressID,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + AddElTypeText + ': ' + AddElementText 
    FROM Results
    WHERE (AddressID = res.AddressID) 
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS AdditionalElements
FROM Results res
GROUP BY res.AddressID
```

Comment: Thanks! To be honest, I wasn't expecting or hopiung for anyone to do the code for me, but with a couple of changes to fit into the specifics I was working with (and a DISTINCT to remove the duplicate rows :-) ), this works fantastically. The other options people have linked to will be really helpful in a few other situations where the DB structure is the same but what I want is different. So again, Thanks all